# Jenkins: PR pipeline triggered by a commit to target branch

Tags: jenkins

I have the following `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        STAGING_BRANCH = 'project'
    }
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Staging Environment') {
            steps {
                sh "sh /bin/create-staging-env"
                }
            }
            when {
                expression { env.CHANGE_TARGET == env.STAGING_BRANCH && env.CHANGE_ID }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The condition `expression { env.CHANGE_TARGET == env.STAGING_BRANCH && env.CHANGE_ID }` is meant to only execute the stage when it is a pull request and the target branch is `project`.

I have this pull request which only has 1 commit:

[image]

But jenkins ran this pipeline multiple (7) times:

[image]

<strike>My guess for the trigger of the additional builds is that when a commit is pushed to another branch, and that branch has a pull request.</strike>

**Edit**
Now I understand why the builds were created. They were caused by commits to the target branch `project`, since the target branch changed by a commit, Jenkins will execute the pipeline for that PR again.

Then my question changes to, How to get which branch the commit that triggered this pipeline is pushed into. For example if a commit is pushed to the `project` branch I would like to ignore the stage for PRs. I want to do something like `expression { ... && env.COMMIT_BRANCH != 'project'}`

Answer (score 1):

Look at the when branch clause for stages. You can tell Jenkins to run stage on particular branches and skip on stage too e.g.

```
stage('PR stuff') {
   when {
       not {
           branch 'project'
       }
   }
   steps {
     sh 'something '
  }
}
```

You can use all of and any of to match multiple clauses in the when too

Comment: Thanks for answering, but because I stopped working on that project, I can't test this solution, but If I had the chance to verify that this works, I will mark it as the accepted. For now take my upvote :)